# Convert OLE Automation Date (OADate) double to struct tm without using VariantTimeToSystemTime

Tags: c++, date, double, coledatetime

I'm writing a Windows DLL in mostly std C++ (VS2010), which does not use MFC/ATL.

A parent module does use MFC and passes a `COleDateTime.m_dt` to my DLL, which arrives as a `double`. I believe this is an OLE Automation Date, also known as OADate.

I want to convert this to any type of standard struct (tm...) that has days, hours, etc without pulling MFC, OLE, etc into my DLL.

This has been asked before ([Convert Date/Time (as Double) to struct* tm in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586812/convert-date-time-as-double-to-struct-tm-in-c)) however, the answer is always using `VariantTimeToSystemTime()`, which misses the point of that question - not using MFC / OLE, etc.

VariantTimeToSystemTime's requirements are:

Header - OleAuto.h
Library - OleAut32.lib
DLL - OleAut32.dll

My DLL has basically no dependencies at the moment, so I would prefer not to pull OleAut32.dll in for this one conversion.

The best thing I've found so far has been this [C# mono code](https://gist.github.com/atifaziz/6b69b87c69ee31166ffe53da3f3fcbb3), which I may convert to C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have 2 solutions, the first is working with a function that implements `gmtime_r` so that this solution will don't use any standard functions. The second solution is using the standard function `gmtime_r`.

**1. First solution: Own implementation of gmtime_r (`01-Jan-1601` to `31-Dec-9999`):**

It will work for dates between `01-Jan-1601` and `31-Dec-9999`. I've implemented a `fromOADate` function which uses the `SecondsSinceEpochToDateTime` function from this [answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11197532/8051589) wich converts seconds before or after `01-Jan-1970` to a `tm` structure but works only from `01-Jan-1601` on.

I changed the function from that answer to work also with 32 bit by adding one `ULL` suffix. That requires that the `long long` types are 64 bit wide, if that's not the case this  solution will not work.

If you need dates before year 1601 you could change the `SecondsSinceEpochToDateTime` as it is well documentated.
To test different values this [online conversion](http://www.silisoftware.com/tools/date.php) is very nice which also supports unix timestamp and the OADate type.

Full working code and [example on ideone](https://ideone.com/R4AueD):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstring>

struct tm* SecondsSinceEpochToDateTime(struct tm* pTm, uint64_t SecondsSinceEpoch)
{
   uint64_t sec;
   unsigned int quadricentennials, centennials, quadrennials, annuals/*1-ennial?*/;
   unsigned int year, leap;
   unsigned int yday, hour, min;
   unsigned int month, mday, wday;
   static const unsigned int daysSinceJan1st[2][13]=
   {
      {0,31,59,90,120,151,181,212,243,273,304,334,365}, // 365 days, non-leap
      {0,31,60,91,121,152,182,213,244,274,305,335,366}  // 366 days, leap
  };
/*
   400 years:

   1st hundred, starting immediately after a leap year that's a multiple of 400:
   n n n l  \
   n n n l   } 24 times
   ...      /
   n n n l /
   n n n n

   2nd hundred:
   n n n l  \
   n n n l   } 24 times
   ...      /
   n n n l /
   n n n n

   3rd hundred:
   n n n l  \
   n n n l   } 24 times
   ...      /
   n n n l /
   n n n n

   4th hundred:
   n n n l  \
   n n n l   } 24 times
   ...      /
   n n n l /
   n n n L <- 97'th leap year every 400 years
*/

   // Re-bias from 1970 to 1601:
   // 1970 - 1601 = 369 = 3*100 + 17*4 + 1 years (incl. 89 leap days) =
   // (3*100*(365+24/100) + 17*4*(365+1/4) + 1*365)*24*3600 seconds
   sec = SecondsSinceEpoch + 11644473600ULL;

   wday = (uint)((sec / 86400 + 1) % 7); // day of week

   // Remove multiples of 400 years (incl. 97 leap days)
   quadricentennials = (uint)(sec / 12622780800ULL); // 400*365.2425*24*3600
   sec %= 12622780800ULL;

   // Remove multiples of 100 years (incl. 24 leap days), can't be more than 3
   // (because multiples of 4*100=400 years (incl. leap days) have been removed)
   centennials = (uint)(sec / 3155673600ULL); // 100*(365+24/100)*24*3600
   if (centennials > 3)
   {
      centennials = 3;
   }
   sec -= centennials * 3155673600ULL;

   // Remove multiples of 4 years (incl. 1 leap day), can't be more than 24
   // (because multiples of 25*4=100 years (incl. leap days) have been removed)
   quadrennials = (uint)(sec / 126230400); // 4*(365+1/4)*24*3600
   if (quadrennials > 24)
   {
      quadrennials = 24;
   }
   sec -= quadrennials * 126230400ULL;

   // Remove multiples of years (incl. 0 leap days), can't be more than 3
   // (because multiples of 4 years (incl. leap days) have been removed)
   annuals = (uint)(sec / 31536000); // 365*24*3600
   if (annuals > 3)
   {
      annuals = 3;
   }
   sec -= annuals * 31536000ULL;

   // Calculate the year and find out if it's leap
   year = 1601 + quadricentennials * 400 + centennials * 100 + quadrennials * 4 + annuals;
   leap = !(year % 4) && (year % 100 || !(year % 400));

   // Calculate the day of the year and the time
   yday = sec / 86400;
   sec %= 86400;
   hour = sec / 3600;
   sec %= 3600;
   min = sec / 60;
   sec %= 60;

   // Calculate the month
   for (mday = month = 1; month < 13; month++)
   {
      if (yday < daysSinceJan1st[leap][month])
      {
         mday += yday - daysSinceJan1st[leap][month - 1];
         break;
      }
   }

   // Fill in C's "struct tm"
   memset(pTm, 0, sizeof(*pTm));
   pTm->tm_sec = sec;          // [0,59]
   pTm->tm_min = min;          // [0,59]
   pTm->tm_hour = hour;        // [0,23]
   pTm->tm_mday = mday;        // [1,31]  (day of month)
   pTm->tm_mon = month - 1;    // [0,11]  (month)
   pTm->tm_year = year - 1900; // 70+     (year since 1900)
   pTm->tm_wday = wday;        // [0,6]   (day since Sunday AKA day of week)
   pTm->tm_yday = yday;        // [0,365] (day since January 1st AKA day of year)
   pTm->tm_isdst = -1;         // daylight saving time flag

   return pTm;
}


struct tm* fromOADate(struct tm* p_Tm, double p_OADate)
{
   static const int64_t OA_UnixTimestamp = -2209161600; /* 30-Dec-1899 */

   if (!(   -109205 <= p_OADate               /* 01-Jan-1601 */
         &&            p_OADate <= 2958465))  /* 31-Dec-9999 */
   {
      throw std::string("OADate must be between 109205 and 2958465!");
   }

   int64_t OADatePassedDays = p_OADate;
   double  OADateDayTime    = p_OADate - OADatePassedDays;
   int64_t OADateSeconds    = OA_UnixTimestamp
                            + OADatePassedDays * 24LL * 3600LL
                            + OADateDayTime * 24.0 * 3600.0;

   return SecondsSinceEpochToDateTime(p_Tm, OADateSeconds);
}


int main()
{
   struct tm timeVal;

   std::cout << asctime(fromOADate(&timeVal, -109205));         /* 01-Jan-1601 00:00:00 */
   std::cout << asctime(fromOADate(&timeVal, 0));               /* 30-Dec-1899 00:00:00 */
   std::cout << asctime(fromOADate(&timeVal, 25569));           /* 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 */
   std::cout << asctime(fromOADate(&timeVal, 50424.134803241)); /* 19-Jan-2038 03:14:07 */
   std::cout << asctime(fromOADate(&timeVal, 2958465));         /* 31-Dec-9999 00:00:00 */

   return 0;
}
```

---

**2. Second solution: Using gmtime_r (`01-Jan-1970` to `19-Jan-2038`/`31-Dec-9999` (32/64 bit)):**

As already said this solution has not that wide range as the variant from above but just uses a standard function ([full working example at ideone](https://ideone.com/NsXOu9)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

struct tm* fromOADate(struct tm* p_Tm, double p_OADate)
{
   static const int64_t OA_UnixTimestamp = -2209161600; /* 30-Dec-1899 */

   if (!(   25569 <= p_OADate              /* 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 */
         &&          p_OADate <= 2958465)) /* 31-Dec-9999 00:00:00 */
   {
      throw std::string("OADate must be between 25569 and 2958465!");
   }

   time_t OADatePassedDays = p_OADate;
   double OADateDayTime    = p_OADate - OADatePassedDays;
   time_t OADateSeconds    = OA_UnixTimestamp
                           + OADatePassedDays * 24LL * 3600LL
                           + OADateDayTime * 24.0 * 3600.0;

   /* date was greater than 19-Jan-2038 and build is 32 bit */
   if (0 > OADateSeconds)
   {
      throw std::string("OADate must be between 25569 and 50424.134803241!");
   }

   return gmtime_r(&OADateSeconds, p_Tm);
}


int main()
{
   struct tm timeVal;

   std::cout << asctime(fromOADate(&timeVal, 25569));           /* 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 */
   std::cout << asctime(fromOADate(&timeVal, 50424.134803241)); /* 19-Jan-2038 03:14:07 */

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.  However, when I compiled it and passed in my COleDateTime.m_dt  (double) the answer that came out was not expected.    COleDateTime time(1999, 3, 19, 22, 15, 0);  came out as 
  tm_sec 16 int
  tm_min 43 int
  tm_hour 4 int
  tm_mday 26 int
  tm_mon 3 int
  tm_year 235 int
  tm_wday 2 int
  tm_yday 115 int
  tm_isdst -1 int

Comment: What is the doubles value exactly?

Comment: Sorry still struggling with SO formatting.  std::cout << asctime(fromOADate(&timeVal, 36238.927083333336));

Comment: OK and what is the value of the double?

Comment: 36238.927083333336

Comment: Fixed that problem by adding `ULL` and `LL` suffixes to some variables. Now it is working on a 32 bit machine too if the `long long` type is 64 bit wide which should be the case on most modern compilers.

Comment: @PhilipBeck: Hi I extend my answer also I fixed something, so take the new code. I added also one method not using an own implementation but using a standard C function (gmtime_r). Also think of accepting the answer to show a wider community that this works.

Comment: Hi Andre

In the hours before your first solution yesterday I had arrived at a simplified version of your second solution.  

tm convertFromOADate(double d)  
{  
 int passedDays = (int)d;  

// 1.1.1970 ->18.1.2038  
 if ((passedDays >= 25569) && (passedDays <= 50423))  
 {  
  time_t t = static_cast<time_t>((d - 25569) * 86400);  
  tm s = *gmtime(&t);  

There's a nice grid of conversions on this page  

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/144159/Time-Format-Conversion-Made-Easy  

I dropped this after seeing your first solution due all of the leap calcs, centuries, etc.

Comment: @PhilipBeck: You simple solution is just using the integral part of the double the passed days but not the time on that day (fractional part). I'm a little bit confused about what you're saying... Well which solution are you using now? If my answer was helpful consider to upvote or/and accept it. If anybody has the same problem he see the answer but thinks it doesn't work as there are no acceptance.

Comment: Thanks Andre, I ultimately used your first solution.